# 'HwMatch' Command not found

Tags: boot

When I go to boot the computer up, I get two errors.

`error: can't find command 'hwmatch'.
error: environment block too small.`

`Press any key to continue...`

I press a key, and guess what.. **Nothing happens!**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More information is needed, i.e. what OS do you use and on what computer with which booting medium?

Comment: I’m running Ubuntu 18.04 on an ASUS X556U

Comment: I’ll find out what booting medium...